# How to make a windows scheduler Start and Stop a python task

Tags: python, windows, scheduler

I have a python script that I typically kick off manually. It then runs for several days collecting information until it gets disconnected.

What I want to do is have the Windows scheduler start the job 12:01 AM and then terminate the job at 11:58 pm that same day.

Typically I would be able to do this using CRON in the linux world but am unsure how to do this in Windows Scheduler.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Task Scheduler in Windows. Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler
2. Click 'Create Basic Task' (to start the script)
3. Set the trigger time
4. Set Program/Script = `[full path to python.exe]`
5. Add Arguments = `[full path to your scheduled python script]`
6. Click 'Create Basic Task' (to end the script)
7. Set the trigger time
8. Program/Script = `taskkill /f /im [full path to python.exe]`

[This guide](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/) goes into more detail.